# Use kwargs in Python ast.Call node

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using the AST library in Python and I need to pass a kwarg to a function that is evaluated by compiling and then eval'ing the syntax tree. I've tried the below in various variations for an ast.Call node but can't get it to work.

`function_node.kwargs = {ast_wrapper(Name, id='use_cache'): ast_wrapper(Num, n=(1 if has_secondary_cache else 0))}`

I get this error:

```
    compiled_formula = compile(formula_object.tree, '<ast>', 'eval')
TypeError: required field "lineno" missing from expr
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the keywards=[] arg in newer versions:

http://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes.html

```
     keywords=[
            keyword(arg='b', value=Name(id='c', ctx=Load())),
            keyword(arg=None, value=Name(id='e', ctx=Load()))   # new in 3.5
         ]))
```